# Check if a user exists node.js mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have user mysql table with users how to get user exists.
i check user using select user from where access token  = .
and check result in node.js server.

```
app.post("/checkStatusUser", function (request, responce) {
  var accessTokenCheck = request.body.accessToken;
  console.log(accessTokenCheck);
  con.query(
    "SELECT * FROM user_token_individual WHERE user_access_token = ?",
    [accessTokenCheck],
    function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        responce.json({
          STATUS_CODES: 404,
        });
        console.log(404);
        responce.end();
      } else {
    

        if (!res.lenght) {
          console.log(res);

          responce.json({
            STATUS_CODES: 200,
          });
          console.log(200);
          responce.end();
        }
        console.log(404);
        responce.end();
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I don’t understand how to check if there is a user with such a token.
in res i have two log 200 and 404 because why i dont understand

Comment: Are you using the NPM Module mysql ???

Comment: yes mysql2 npm modules

Comment: If the question is why you need to send 200 if the user exists and 404 if it does not, then the answer is that these are standard http response codes. 200 means the request was processed just fine, 404 means that the requested resource (ie. the user) does not exists. But you do not seem to execute the query.

Comment: I don’t understand how to check if there is a user with such a token

Comment: Ok well, hopefully terry's answer worked for you. His answer is that standard way of checking a database for a user. I also agree that a 404 is not appropriate for your case-senario. Personally I suggest not serving an http status at all. Instead give them a failed login page, with the ability to try again. It will be frustrating for your sites/apps users to be forced to use the URL-Address Bar on each failed login attempt, however; if you feel that you absolutely need to serve the HTTP status, use  '401: Unauthorized'. HTTP-401 is the go to for failed authorization attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [response.status](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status) function to indicate status to the user, you can then use [response.json](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) to indicate the message. You could also use [response.sendStatus](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus) if you just want to send text status, this would append a message to the response.

I'd suggest using a 500 status code in the case of an error, this indicates something we didn't expect, this is up to you of course!!

So something like this should work:

```
app.post("/checkStatusUser", function (request, responce) {
    var accessTokenCheck = request.body.accessToken;
    console.log(accessTokenCheck);
    con.query(
        "SELECT * FROM user_token_individual WHERE user_access_token = ?",
        [accessTokenCheck],
        function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("An error occurred:", err.message);
                responce.status(500).json({ status: 500, message: "An error occurred: " + err.message });
            } else {
                if (res.length) {
                    console.log( "User found successfully.");
                    responce.status(200).json({ status: 200, message: "User found successfully." });
                } else {
                    console.log( "User not found.");
                    responce.status(404).send({ status: 404, message: "User not found." });
                }
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: i have a problem with res.lenght is always equals ```undefined``` even when user exist

Comment: Oh, yes I see. Is it possible that you want res.length rather than res.lenght? Could it be a simple typo?

Comment: sorry i search my problem been in ```res.lenght ``` th